# Запись радио стрима

Tags: ubuntu, icecast

На сервере стоит `icecast` который вещает радио и есть скрипт который пишет в определенное время радио поток. Сам поток пишется с помощью утилиы `Streamripper`, так вот вчера начало сыпаться большое кол-во ошибок при записи потока, решил сделать запрос на радио поток и получил такую ошибку.

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Latino/Cadena"
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Подскажите с чем это связано? Раньше не сталкивался с данной проблемой

Comment: С тем, что радио выключено, например?

Comment: забанили фаерволом, проверяют user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Оказалось что у icecast стоял лимит соединений, и когда он был достигнут все остальные запросы к нему возвращались с ошибкой!